# matplotlib pnpoly example results in error

Tags: python, matplotlib, attributeerror, point-in-polygon

I ran the following code as per the example here:

http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#test-whether-a-point-is-inside-a-polygon

I would kindly appreciate your help. Thank you.

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>import matplotlib.nxutils as nx
>>>verts = np.array([ [0,0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1,0]], float)
>>>nx.pnpoly(0.5, 0.5, verts)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\nxutils.py", line 26, in pnpoly
    return p.contains_point(x, y)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\path.py", line 289, in contains_point
    transform = transform.frozen()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'frozen'

>>>nx.pnpoly(0.5, 1.5, verts)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\nxutils.py", line 26, in pnpoly
    return p.contains_point(x, y)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\path.py", line 289, in contains_point
    transform = transform.frozen()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'frozen'
```

Comment: I got this warning when I tested it `/home/tcaswell/local_installs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/nxutils.py:23: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: nxutils is deprecated.  Use matplotlib.path.Path.contains_point instead.`

Comment: but that shouldnt prevent it from working?

Comment: I wish they would update their documentation. Grrr. Thank you for pointing this out. Appreciate it.

Comment: You should create an issue about this (and suggest an improved example!).  MPL is a big project with lots of moving parts, any help keep them up is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user on the matplotlib forum provided the following, which works as I tested:

```
from matplotlib.path import Path
path = Path(polygonVerts)
isInside = path.contains_point(point)
```

Answer (score 2):

Though `pnpoly` has been deprecated, your error was caused by a bug which has since been fixed in [this commit on GitHub](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/f9c7b67157f17d1edd243177b88f4584cc77f3d9).

The error resulted from `pnpoly` proxying through to `contains_point` with the wrong method signature.